# How can I clean a string in bashrc?

Tags: bash

I'd like to know how to "clean up" a line of code in `bash`. I've created a string to colour the command line in my `~/.bashrc` which looks like this:

```
PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

I'd like to make it easier to discern. More something along these lines:

```
PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]
     \u\[\033[1;31m\]
     @\[\033[1;32m\]
     \h:\[\033[1;35m\]
     \w\[\033[1;31m\]
     \$\[\033[0m\] '
```

I've tried putting these `{}` brackets but that didn't seem to work, either.

EDIT: thanks to tripleee. The code that works is as follows:

```
tprompt () {
    local bold=$(tput bold)
    local red=$(tput setaf 1)
    local green=$(tput setaf 2)
    local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    local plain=$(tput sgr0)
    printf -v PS1 "%s" "$bold" "$cyan" '\u' \
        "$red" "@" \
        "$green" '\h:' \
        "$magenta" '\w' \
        "$red" '\$' \
        "$plain"
}
tprompt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better overall approach might be to use `tput` to generate these codes, rather than hard-code them for a specific terminal. This also allows you to assign mnemonic names to them.

```sh
tprompt () {
    local bold=$(tput bold)
    local red=$(tput setaf 1)
    local green=$(tput setaf 2)
    local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    local plain=$(tput sgr0)
    printf -v PS1 "%s" "$bold" "$cyan" '\u' \
        "$red" "@" \
        "$green" '\h:' \
        "$magenta" '\w' \
        "$red" '\$' \
        "$plain" ' '
}
tprompt
```

(Not sure I managed to correctly map back the escape codes to their meanings, but you should at least be able to see how this is more readable and maintainable than what you had. The sole reason to define a function for this is to create a `local` scope so the helper variables don't pollute the global namespace. We only call the function once; you could even undefine the function when you have called it, too.)

As an aside, notice also how `printf` lets you easily paste together multiple strings. Even if you don't adopt this approach wholesale, you might want to refactor to

```sh
printf -v PS1 '%s' \
     '\[\033[1;36m\]' \
     '\u\[\033[1;31m\]' \
     '@\[\033[1;32m\]' \
     '\h:\[\033[1;35m\]' \
     '\w\[\033[1;31m\]' \
     '\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

As a final aside, non-printing sequences in the prompt should be wrapped in `\[` ... `\]` to tell Bash to disregard them when calculating the line length. Maybe wrap `tput` with a function, too:

```
tput () {
    printf '\\['
    command tput "$@"
    printf '\\]'
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I like how clean the code is now. Btw, the `setgr0` gave an erroneous output `tput: unknown terminfo capability 'setgr0'` but I googled and found out that the parameter needs to be `sgr0`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the sloppy mistake. Updated now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I am experiencing a weird bug. I suspect it is due to the code you provided. I made a [gif](https://imguh.com/image/ZcLPs) about it so that you can see what happens.

Comment: You'll need to wrap non-printing escape sequences in `\[` ... `\]` inside the prompt. I'll update the answer to mention this, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. It looks like I managed to solve it by removing the space and the `'` at the end of the code. It looks like this now:
`tprompt () {
    local bold=$(tput bold)
    local red=$(tput setaf 1)  
    local green=$(tput setaf 2)  
    local magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    local cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    local plain=$(tput sgr0)
    printf -v PS1 "%s" "$bold" "$cyan" '\u' \
        "$red" "@" \
        "$green" '\h:' \
        "$magenta" '\w' \
        "$red" '\$' \
        "$plain"
}
tprompt`
EDIT: oh, God... the formatting :(